# Has someone correctly predicted one of the variants of SARS-CoV-2 (like the Delta variant)?

Tags: reference-request, prediction, biology, healthcare

Without any evidence, I have wondered it might be possible to predict the upcoming mutations of the COVID-19 virus. I am further assuming people did so.

So, has someone correctly predicted the emergence of one of the variants of SARS-CoV-2 (like the Delta variant)?

I would be happy to have an explanation in layman's terms and citations to papers (if any).

Comment: They probably failed, otherwise Covid won't be such a world-wide pandemic.

Answer (score 1):

[Atomwise](https://www.atomwise.com/), an AI startup, uses a 3d convolution neural network to predict if a molecule will bind to an protein. The covid protein had several human attempts to find a molecule to bind.

See on young inventors approach to solving covid

https://www.cnn.com/2020/10/18/us/anika-chebrolu-covid-treatment-award-scn-trnd/index.html

> Anika's winning invention uses in-silico methodology to discover a lead molecule that can selectively bind to the spike protein of the SARS-CoV-2 virus.

I wonder if the atomwise simulator would concur that lead would bind to the spike protein